# Deshabilitar hash en AdonisJs

Tags: adonisjs, adonis-5

Estoy trabajando con un framework de `Node.js`, `AdonisJs`, y por ciertos motivos necesito deshabilitar el hasheo porque al querer realizar un login y verificar los datos en la base de datos los intenta comprobar hasheados y no lo estan, lo que causa un error.

No hay código que pueda postearles porque no se que podría adjuntar, disculpas.

Estoy trabajando con la version 5 de Adonis y el login esta hecho con `Auth` que es un paquete del mismo.

> Intenté quitar de las configuraciones de hash la opción pensando que al no encontrarlo no lo pediría.

Comment: Ya edité la publicación, gracias por tus observaciones!

Comment: Agregué lo que pediste, aunque no fue mucho porque no se me ocurrio mucho que hacer

Comment: *verificar los datos en la base de datos los intenta comprobar hasheados y no lo estan* :/ pues muy preocupante, los passwords deben ser almacenados como hash y no como texto plano, desde el día 0 de desarrollo. No es algo *que dejo para después*. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pienso que lejos de considerar: *Deshabilitar hash.....* (como expones en tu pregunta) puedes emplear (**de manera temporal**) la siguiente opción (**al menos en lo que proteges las credenciales de acceso**), por ejemplo:

- Iniciar la sesión del usuario por medio de su id, lo cual implica que primero se deba verificar que el mismo exista en la base de datos

  ```
   const usuarioIngresa = await User.query().where("columna", valorQueLlega).first()

   await auth.use("web").loginViaId(usuarioIngresa.id)
  ```

Comentarios finales:

- Solo tendrás que considerar que valor solicitas del usuario por ejemplo para posterior realizar la búsqueda del mismo
- Ya sea que uses el método [`attempt`](https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/auth/web-guard#login) o el método [`login`](https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/auth/web-guard#authlogin) deberías en todo momento tener *hasheadas* las contraseñas de los usuarios
- **Esta *respuesta* debe considerarse solo como una solución temporal en lo que se fortalecen todos los aspectos ya mencionados y no como una solución definitiva**
- No desaproveches [las funcionalidades](https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/security/hashing) al respecto que ya ofrece el framework, tales como:

  - Argon2
  - Bcrypt

Comment: Muchas gracias!!